# Best approach to Notification Sounds on Web Apps

Tags: java, laravel, vue.js, google-chrome, mozilla

I have a Delivery System that I made with Laravel + Vue.Js and all is working fine, but I'm facing some problems with Notification Sounds.

When the client makes an order on his cellphone or pc, I need to show a Notification sound alert with a custom sound to admin from the Restaurant.

But when I'm working with Chrome or Mozilla, sometimes my Notification doesn't show up and the custom sound only plays if the admin stays on the web page but not in another tab or minimized.

I want to make this process 100% with the sound and the Notification always showing.

When I see another competitor's software I see that they have a small java desktop application only to do that. I can do some similar with Electron?

But I don't have any idea where to start making some like this or the name is called.

Here is my code for notification on my Web Application, I'm using FCM:

```
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("{{url('firebase/sw-js')}}")
            .then((registration) => {
                messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
                messaging.requestPermission()
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                        getRegToken();

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
                    });

                var audio = new Audio('urltosound.mp3');
                messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
                    console.log("Message received. ", payload);
                    notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
                    notificationOptions = {
                        body: payload.data.body,
                        icon: payload.data.icon,
                        image: payload.data.image,
                        requireInteraction: true,
                    };
                    var notification = new Notification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
                    notification.onshow = function() {
                        audio.play();
                        audio.loop = true;
                    };
                    notification.onclose = function() {
                        audio.pause();
                        audio.currentTime = 0;
                    };
                    notification.onclick = function() {
                        audio.pause();
                        audio.currentTime = 0;
                        // window.location.href = '/administrativo/orders/' + payload.data.orderid;
                        window.open('/administrativo/orders/' + payload.data.orderid, '_blank');
                    };
                    notification.addEventListener('close', () => {
                        audio.pause();
                        audio.currentTime = 0;
                    });
                });
            });
```

It is working but when we are playing with Notification and Custom Sound on a Browser I'm not very confident that always will play and show and this can't happen.

Comment: Why have you tagged this Java? Are you trying to make this sound in the browser (eg via **Javascript** not Java), or is this some sort of Java-based application?

Comment: I have a web application and I'm trying to play this sound with a simple javascript I will update my answer with the code. I talk about java because I can mad desktop application with it and I'm thinking that with the desktop application the sound will play 100% or I'm wrong?